# lubuntu vs ubuntu decision for a Dell Dell XPS 400

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, dell

Lubuntu is advertised as lightweight and good for older hardware. 
   The Dell is circa 2005.

- Ubuntu 16.04 recommends 512MB
  (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/ch03s04.html).
- Lubuntu is recommending 1GB (http://lubuntu.net/).

I installed Ubuntu and the UI response seems to be very slow.  I am tempted to try Lubuntu, but before I do, I wanted to ask if I should expect the same or a snappy response?

Bonus if you have installed both on your system and can compare the two.  Trifecta if you have the XPS 400 running either Ubuntu and can comment

Comment: "Ubuntu 16.04 recommends 512MB (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/ch03s04.html)." This is crazy. Ubuntu 16.04 uses over 1GB RAM when idle on my ThinkPad, and I've even disabled a number of default applications like Evolution.

Comment: There are two issues with that minimum requirement. 1: it's old, and 2: it's for Ubuntu Server, which has no GUI at all.

Comment: If you're really looking for lightning speed, look to Lubuntu or Xubuntu for Ubuntu variants, and then take a look at Puppy or one of CrunchBang's successors for other distributions.

Comment: There is no shadow of a doubt here: Lubuntu is the lightest of all Ubuntu flavors, because lxde is the lightest desktop environment used by official Ubuntus.

Comment: The Dell machine had a mere 512MB of RAM so Ubuntu was not usuable.  On the other hand lubuntu was usable.   An upgrade to 2GB is in the near future.

Answer (score 5):

Lubuntu will almost certainly perform better. My brother had an old 512MB Dell desktop that I brought back to life. I first tried vanilla Ubuntu but it lagged horribly, then tried Lubuntu and it ran like it was brand new.

Answer (score 1):

I have both Ubuntu and Lubuntu 16.04 on my older HP Pavilion desktop with 1 GByte RAM. Ubuntu will bog down and run slow. Lubuntu is more responsive. The good thing is that they run the same software except for the desktop environment: Unity versus LXLE. I don't feel I've lost anything by running Lubuntu.